# Need to make two buttons align a few pixels left and right of the center

Tags: html, css

Need to make two buttons align a few pixels left and right of the centre
I need div left to be 1px to the left of the centre. And right to be 1px right of it.

Any ideas how?

```css
.btn {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn2 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.divleft {
  margin: auto 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.divright {
  margin: auto 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="divleft"> <a href="en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori" class="btn">Memento</a> </div>
<div class="divright"> <a href="discord.gg/j9Bh6mSjf2" class="btn2">Mori</a> </div>
```

Comment: Plz, include the HTML also.

Comment: @Potta update HTML to your question, not in comment bro

Comment: @dungmidside np there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn2 {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori" class="btn">Memento</a>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <a href="discord.gg/j9Bh6mSjf2" class="btn2">Mori</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/jOMgpbd

Answer (score 0):

I created a CodePen that shows how to make it work: https://codepen.io/kaireidcasey/pen/rNMXrde

The parent element needs display: flex set on it. The children each need an auto margin on one side. I am sure there are other ways to solve this, as well.

Code snippets:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="divleft">
    <a href="en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori" class="btn">Memento</a>
  </div>
  <div class="divright">
    <a href="discord.gg/j9Bh6mSjf2" class="btn2">Mori</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn2 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.divleft {
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.divright {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```